# Preserve divisions in Dask dataframe after join

Tags: python, dask

Let say I'm in the following situation:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import random
s = "abcd"
lst = 10*[0]+list(range(1,6))
n = int(1e2)

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [random.choice(s) for i in range(n)],
                   "col2": [random.choice(lst) for i in range(n)]})
df["idx"] = df.col1
df = df[["idx","col1","col2"]]

def fun(data):
    if data["col2"].mean()>1:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

df.set_index("idx", inplace=True)
ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)
gpb = ddf1.groupby("col1").apply(fun, meta=pd.Series(name='col3'))
ddf2 = ddf1.join(gpb.to_frame(), on="col1")
```

While `ddf1.known_divisions` is `True` `ddf2.known_divisions` is `False` I would like to preserve the same division on the `ddf2` dataframe. 
In one random example what I even got an empty partition.

```
for i in range(ddf1.npartitions):
    print(i, len(ddf1.get_partition(i)), len(ddf2.get_partition(i)))

0 27 50
1 29 0
2 23 21
3 21 29
```